# How to reload adView on onConfigurationChanged?

Tags: android, admob, adview

in Manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/MyThemeDetails"
            android:name="Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

so when i rotate device onCreate doesn't call again, that's why adView doesn't reload with `AdSize.SMART_BANNER` and size remains 320x50 in landscape mode 
[image]
But I need in landscape mode size (full_wigthx32) (screen below)
[image]

**What I need to add in onConfigurationChanged to reload size of adView?**

```
 private void addBaner() {
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ads_id));
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l_edds);
            adLayout.addView(adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        }


 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work?

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    addBanner();
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. This happens http://i.stack.imgur.com/6I61S.png

Comment: Other than non being centered it looks like it works to me. NB you can solve the centering issue by placing your AdView in its own container.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include correctly the AdActivity in your manifest?

```
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```